# Background image appearing between content on zooming in

Tags: html, css, jsp, svg, sass

I have this image that I want as the *background* for the index page. But when I zoom in the background images appears between the form fields instead of going behind the form as it should. The **body** of the index page comprises a **main** element which consists of an **aside** element and a **section**. The **section** contains two forms, one for **login** and another for **sign up** with 2 buttons for the same. For clarity, vide the code given below.

1) The main problem I am facing is when I zoom in, approximately around and beyond 400%. The background image appears between the "email" and "password" fields of the login-form(active) on zooming in. I want the background image to actually be in the background and stay behind all of the content of the **main** tag, i.e basically behind the entire form and the aside image.

2) Additionally, you may notice when you zoom in that the log in or the sign up button do not appear at the end of the form, rather they appear mid-way with a big white space below it. I want those buttons to be at the very bottom of the form on zooming in.

3) Lastly, one may also notice how the upper portion of the svg image I have used in the aside tag is cut off when zoomed in and repositioned. With that, the intro text below the svg also appear behind the "LOGIN" and "SIGN UP" anchor tags when zoomed in. It would be nicer if they would all be non-overlapping or not cropped off.

P.S.- I have used inline **svg**. So skip or fold the long piece of svg code to not be agonised.(*Brownie points for someone who can suggest how to use external svg with the animation working. I have tried *object*, *embed* and *img* but to no avail*).

You can use any downloaded image as background by placing it inside the ***img*** folder and naming it "*bg-index.jpeg*".

> HTML/JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
    <title>Login << Exam Nation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <meta name="description" content="Take an Exam--Test Yourself | Exam Nation " />
    <meta name="keywords" content="exam nation, online examination system, log in, sign up, index, default page, fallback page" />
    <meta name="author" content="Akash Das" />
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/lkh0ago.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<!--===============================================================================================-->      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
</head>

<!--style="background: url(img/bg-index.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;"-->
<body>

<main ontouchstart class="with-hover">
    <aside>
        <div></div>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <g stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path d="M65.892702,73 C70.3362168,68.5836139 73.0845878,62.4824333 73.0845878,55.7432553 C73.0845878,49.0040774 70.3362168,42.9028968 65.892702,38.4865107 C61.4491873,34.0701246 55.3105288,31.338533 48.5299539,31.338533 C41.749379,31.338533 35.6107205,34.0701246 31.1672058,38.4865107 C26.723691,42.9028968 23.97532,49.0040774 23.97532,55.7432553 C23.97532,62.4824333 26.723691,68.5836139 31.1672058,73 C31.1672058,73 65.892702,73 65.892702,73 Z M73.0594097,62.3985471 C76.4680437,61.2200182 88.5607213,56.1793944 85.5117743,37.8371245 L81.6924976,37.9360303 C80.8526284,43.134546 77.152648,46.6051883 72.4845099,46.6051883 M24.4062209,60.319036 C24.3904842,60.3191058 24.3747393,60.3191408 24.3589862,60.3191408 C18.6378761,60.3191408 14,55.70958 14,50.0233985 C14,44.3372171 18.6378761,39.7276563 24.3589862,39.7276563 C26.0569266,39.7276563 27.6594543,40.133673 29.0736464,40.8533508 M65.8946819,38.4867877 L31.1652244,38.4844448 M37.6782363,44.9577899 C34.9010396,47.7180312 33.1833077,51.5312691 33.1833077,55.7432553 C33.1833077,59.9552416 34.9010396,63.7684794 37.6782363,66.5287208 M45.4606247,29.0505903 L51.5992831,29.0505903 M48.5299539,26 L48.5299539,31.338533"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
        <div>
            <p id="intro-signup"><br/>Be a citizen of&nbsp;<strong>Exam Nation</strong> with&nbsp;an&nbsp;account.</p>
            <p id="intro-login" class="active"><br/>Welcome back to<br/><strong>Exam Nation</strong>!</p>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <section>
        <h1>
            <a id="link-login" class="active">Login</a>
            <a id="link-signup">Register</a>
        </h1>
        <form id="form-signup" action="test1.html" method="POST">
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <div>
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <div>
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="abc@xyz.com" required/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <div>
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="••••••••" required/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <button class="fb">Connect with Facebook</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="tw">Connect with Twitter</button>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
        </form>
        <form id="form-login" class="active" action="test2.html" method="POST">
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <div>
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="abc@xyz.com" required/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <div>
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="••••••••" required/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <button class="fb">Connect with Facebook</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="tw">Connect with Twitter</button>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
        </form>
    </section>
</main>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</body>

</html>
```

> CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

*:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url(../img/bg-index.jpeg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "brandon-grotesque", "Brandon Grotesque", "Source Sans Pro", "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #857567;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

main {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
}
main aside {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 12px;
  background: #DFB72C url("../img/table-pc.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
}
.
.
.
main aside svg {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -24px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
main aside p {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding : 5px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(133, 117, 103, 0.5);
}
main aside p strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}
main section form input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  align-self: flex-end;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: "brandon-grotesque", "Brandon Grotesque", "Source Sans Pro", "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 2;
  background: #DFB72C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.
.
.
@media only screen and (min-width: 624px) {
  body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: url(../img/bg-index.jpeg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  main {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 370px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(56, 54, 53, 0.5);
  }
```

> SCREENSHOTS

**a. Login Page without zoom**
[image: Login Page without zoom]
**b. Login Page with 500% zoom**
[image: Page with 500% zoom]
**c. Login Page with 400% zoom**
[image: Page with 400% zoom]
**d. White weird space after the log in button on 500% zoom**
[image: White weird space after the log in button on 500% zoom]
**e. On zooming in, the intro-text goes behind the LOGIN & REGISTER anchors. The svg image is cut off.**
[image: On zooming in, the intro-text goes behind the LOGIN & REGISTER anchors. The svg image is cut off.]

**EDIT:-** *For complete CSS code(minus the webkit-keyframes), see the answer below. I have also attached the background image herewith.*

Comment: I was only able to reproduce the problem in firefox but you have some negative margin-top's (for example on main aside div:not(:empty) ), that together with the fixed height of the aside cause the background to show up.

Comment: @StevenKuipers Thanks for the insight. Can you suggest a working solution for the aforementioned background problem with the help of some code?

Comment: @StevenKuipers And it would be honey-a-sauce-to-sugar if you could let me know about fixing the issue with the submit buttons(Log In and Sign Up) buttons not appearing at the end of the forms on zooming in. This is making it look odd when the zoom is at 500%

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full CSS code. I had reached the word-limit for the question.

> CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

*:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url(../img/bg-index.jpeg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "brandon-grotesque", "Brandon Grotesque", "Source Sans Pro", "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #857567;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

main {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
}
main aside {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 12px;
  background: #DFB72C url("../img/table-pc.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
}
main aside div:empty {
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #DFB72C url("../img/table-pc.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
}
main aside svg {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -24px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
main aside div:not(:empty) {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -24px;
}
main aside p {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding : 5px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(133, 117, 103, 0.5);
}
main aside p strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}
main aside p:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
main aside p.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: none;
          transform: none;
}
main aside p:not(.active) {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
          transform: translateY(100px);
}
main section {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% / 3 * 2);
}
main section h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 18px;
  color: #DFB72C;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
main section h1 a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: none;
          transform: none;
}
main section h1 a:hover, main section h1 a:focus {
  color: #976a36;
}
main section h1 a:active {
  color: #857567;
}
main section h1 a.active {
  font-weight: 500;
}
main section h1 a:not(.active) {
  font-weight: 300;
}
main section form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
main section form > div, main section form > ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px;
}
main section form fieldset {
  padding: 6px;
}
main section form fieldset div {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
main section form fieldset div label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 9px;
  background: #DFB72C;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 25px;
}
main section form fieldset div input {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #DFB72C;
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 9px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #857567;
  font-family: "brandon-grotesque", "Brandon Grotesque", "Source Sans Pro", "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
main section form fieldset div input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(133, 117, 103, 0.4);
}
main section form fieldset div input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(133, 117, 103, 0.4);
}
main section form fieldset div input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(133, 117, 103, 0.4);
}
main section form fieldset div input::placeholder {
  color: rgba(133, 117, 103, 0.4);
}
main section form fieldset div input:focus {
  background: rgba(233, 226, 213, 0.5);
}
main section form fieldset div input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(133, 117, 103, 0.6);
}
main section form fieldset div input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(133, 117, 103, 0.6);
}
main section form fieldset div input:focus::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(133, 117, 103, 0.6);
}
main section form fieldset div input:focus::placeholder {
  color: rgba(133, 117, 103, 0.6);
}
main section form li {
  padding: 6px;
}
main section form li button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  font-family: "brandon-grotesque", "Brandon Grotesque", "Source Sans Pro", "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
main section form li button.fb {
  background: #3b5998;
}
main section form li button.fb:hover, main section form li button.fb:focus {
  background: #5f7ec1;
}
main section form li button.fb:active {
  background: #263961;
}
main section form li button.tw {
  background: #00aced;
}
main section form li button.tw:hover, main section form li button.tw:focus {
  background: #3bc9ff;
}
main section form li button.tw:active {
  background: #0074a1;
}
main section form input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  align-self: flex-end;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: "brandon-grotesque", "Brandon Grotesque", "Source Sans Pro", "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 2;
  background: #DFB72C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
main section form input[type="submit"]:hover, main section form input[type="submit"]:focus {
  background: #976a36;
}
main section form input[type="submit"]:active {
  background: #857567;
}
main section form.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
main section form.active fieldset, main section form.active li, main section form.active input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}
main section form:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
main section form:not(.active) fieldset, main section form:not(.active) li, main section form:not(.active) input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
          transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
}
main.with-hover aside p {
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
main.with-hover section h1 a {
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}
main.with-hover section h1 a:hover, main.with-hover section h1 a:focus {
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
main.with-hover section h1 a:active {
  transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}
main.with-hover section form {
  transition: all 1000ms ease-out;
}
main.with-hover section form fieldset, main.with-hover section form li, main.with-hover section form input[type="submit"] {
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}
main.with-hover section form button, main.with-hover section form input {
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}
main.with-hover section form button:hover, main.with-hover section form button:focus, main.with-hover section form input:hover, main.with-hover section form input:focus {
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
main.with-hover section form button:active, main.with-hover section form input:active {
  transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}
main.with-hover section form.active#form-signup fieldset:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 50ms;
}
main.with-hover section form.active#form-signup fieldset:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}
main.with-hover section form.active#form-signup li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 150ms;
}
main.with-hover section form.active#form-signup li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}
main.with-hover section form.active#form-signup input[type="submit"] {
  transition-delay: 250ms;
}
main.with-hover section form.active#form-login fieldset:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 50ms;
}
main.with-hover section form.active#form-login li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}
main.with-hover section form.active#form-login li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 150ms;
}
main.with-hover section form.active#form-login input[type="submit"] {
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}
main.with-hover section form:not(.active)#form-signup fieldset:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 250ms;
}
main.with-hover section form:not(.active)#form-signup fieldset:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}
main.with-hover section form:not(.active)#form-signup fieldset:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 150ms;
}
main.with-hover section form:not(.active)#form-signup li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}
main.with-hover section form:not(.active)#form-signup li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 50ms;
}
main.with-hover section form:not(.active)#form-login fieldset:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}
main.with-hover section form:not(.active)#form-login fieldset:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 150ms;
}
main.with-hover section form:not(.active)#form-login li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}
main.with-hover section form:not(.active)#form-login li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 50ms;
}
main.pre-enter aside {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
          transform-origin: center top;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
          transform: scaleY(0);
  visibility: hidden;
}
main.pre-enter aside svg {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
          transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(90deg);
          transform: scale(0) rotate(90deg);
  visibility: hidden;
}
main.pre-enter aside p.active {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
          transform: translateY(100px);
  visibility: hidden;
}
main.pre-enter section h1 a {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
main.pre-enter section h1 a:first-child {
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
          transform-origin: right center;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200px) scaleX(0);
          transform: translateX(200px) scaleX(0);
}
main.pre-enter section h1 a:last-child {
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
          transform-origin: left center;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200px) scaleX(0);
          transform: translateX(-200px) scaleX(0);
}
main.pre-enter section form fieldset, main.pre-enter section form li {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
          transform: translateY(100px);
  visibility: hidden;
}
main.pre-enter section form input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
          transform-origin: center bottom;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
          transform: scaleY(0);
  color: #DFB72C;
  visibility: hidden;
}
main.on-enter aside {
  -webkit-animation: scaleYIn 1000ms linear forwards;
          animation: scaleYIn 1000ms linear forwards;
  visibility: visible;
}
main.on-enter aside svg {
  -webkit-animation: bounceIn-rotate 1000ms linear forwards 250ms;
          animation: bounceIn-rotate 1000ms linear forwards 250ms;
  visibility: visible;
}
main.on-enter aside p.active {
  -webkit-animation: slideInUp-fadeIn 1000ms linear forwards 500ms;
          animation: slideInUp-fadeIn 1000ms linear forwards 500ms;
  visibility: visible;
}
main.on-enter section h1 a {
  visibility: visible;
}
main.on-enter section h1 a:first-child {
  -webkit-animation: scaleX-slideInRight 1000ms linear forwards 750ms;
          animation: scaleX-slideInRight 1000ms linear forwards 750ms;
}
main.on-enter section h1 a:last-child {
  -webkit-animation: scaleX-slideInLeft 1000ms linear forwards 750ms;
          animation: scaleX-slideInLeft 1000ms linear forwards 750ms;
}
main.on-enter section form fieldset, main.on-enter section form li {
  -webkit-animation: slideInUp-fadeIn 1000ms linear forwards;
          animation: slideInUp-fadeIn 1000ms linear forwards;
  visibility: visible;
}
main.on-enter section form fieldset:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1250ms;
          animation-delay: 1250ms;
}
main.on-enter section form fieldset:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1350ms;
          animation-delay: 1350ms;
}
main.on-enter section form fieldset:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1450ms;
          animation-delay: 1450ms;
}
main.on-enter section form li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1550ms;
          animation-delay: 1550ms;
}
main.on-enter section form li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1650ms;
          animation-delay: 1650ms;
}
main.on-enter section form input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-animation: scaleYIn 1000ms linear forwards 1750ms, lemon-white 250ms linear forwards 2150ms;
          animation: scaleYIn 1000ms linear forwards 1750ms, lemon-white 250ms linear forwards 2150ms;
  visibility: visible;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 624px) {
  body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: url(../img/bg-index.jpeg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  main {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 370px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(56, 54, 53, 0.5);
  }
  main aside, main section {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
  }
  main.pre-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  main.pre-enter aside {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
  main.on-enter {
    -webkit-animation: slideDown-fadeIn 1000ms linear forwards;
            animation: slideDown-fadeIn 1000ms linear forwards;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  main.on-enter aside {
    -webkit-animation: none;
            animation: none;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes lemon-white {
  0% {
    color: #DFB72C;
  }
  100% {
    color: white;
  }
}
@keyframes lemon-white {
  0% {
    color: #DFB72C;
  }
  100% {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

> Background Image

**bg-index.jpeg**
[image]